# how to compress image Size for Save memory

Tags: images

i have to compress image after upload anyone give me code for image compress?

Can any one help me.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Not available out of the box. Vote here - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kuUPAAY